# python requests response.url times out

Tags: python-3.x, api, url, python-requests

Based on the manual this is a valid URL :
http://aiws.intra.infocamere.it/aiws/rest/registroimprese/bilanci/ricerca/partitaiva

I need to set the partitaIva parameter like this: partitaIva = "XXXXXXXXXXXX"

So the url becomes :  http://aiws.intra.infocamere.it/aiws/rest/registroimprese/bilanci/ricerca/partitaiva?partitaIva=XXXXXXXX

After authentication which I'm sure works (tried on a generic url of website, url3) I print the response.url which times out.

Here is the code:

```
import requests
url2 = "http://aiws.intra.infocamere.it/aiws/rest/registroimprese/bilanci/ricerca/partitaiva"
url3 = "http://login.infocamere.it/eacologin/login.action"
payload2 = {'partitaIva': 'XXXXXXXXX'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'curl'} 

r = requests.get(url2,
                 auth=('user', 'psw'),
                 params=payload2,
                 headers=headers,
                 stream=True,
                 timeout=10)
print(r.url)
print(r.status_code)
```

I'm sure the URL is correct, as well, since in their website they generate the URL as it is.

My question is how to know why there is a timeout? What causes the timeout? Even the `response.status_code` times out.

Comment: May I ask you why you have url2 and url3, while you're using only url2? And, yes, this seems to be more related to the website owner, not requests.

Comment: @ThomasKlinger I used url3 to show that authentication works. there is no response and only timeout, even removing timeout parameter it will time out. I used postman and the same there.

Comment: Well, then ask the owner of the website, this is nothing related to requests or even Python, when you get a timeout with your browser and any REST client.

Comment: @ThomasKlinger why -1? are you sure of your answer?

Comment: Pretty sure. When the endpoint's not answering it can't be the fault of Python or requests.

Answer (score 0):

In this case to create the URL instead of defining the `auth` parameter to send credentials, I had to send the dictionary of username and password as headers like below:

```
import requests
url2 = "http://aiws.intra.infocamere.it/aiws/rest/registroimprese/bilanci/ricerca/partitaiva"
headers = {'username': 'user', 'password': 'psw'}
r = requests.get(url2,
                 # auth=(user, psw),
                 params=payload2,
                 headers=headers,
                 stream=True,
                 timeout=10)
```